# Adding a filter to Aggregate query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i'm trying to add a filter to my query in MongoDB to only return results after a certain date. I need to retrieve only dates from the transaction.CreatedAt column which are after the 11th Nov this year. I'm pretty new to MongoDB but really struggling to solve this. Any help would be awesome!

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
      {
        from: 'lessons',
        localField: 'productId.id',  
        foreignField: '_id',     
        as: 'product'
      }
    },
    {$unwind:'$product'},
    {
      $lookup:
      {
        from: 'schools',
        localField: 'schoolId',  
        foreignField: '_id',     
        as: 'provider'
      }
    },
    {$unwind:'$provider'},
    {
      $lookup:
      {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'userId',  
        foreignField: '_id',   
        as: 'user'
      }
    },
    {$unwind:'$user'},
])
.projection({_id:1, createdAt:1, 'user.email':1})
   .sort({_id:-1})
   .limit(1500)
```

I tried to add the filter into the projection but couldn't get anything to run when I used $filter.
Tried below just using a $gte

```
projection({_id:1, createdAt:{ $gte: [ "createdAt", Date("2022-11-21T11:45:28+00:00")] }
```

Comment: 4 collections in a single query does not look like a smart data design. Usually the number of collections in a NoSQL database like MongoDB is much less than the number of tables in according relational SQL database. Some NoSQL database do not support joins at all.

Comment: You may want to put your criteria in a [$match](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage.